# How do I control the size and layout of child views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm diving into iOS development and I'm trying to figure out how to control the size and layout of multiple child views (in this case, two child views).  I posted this question in a different context and my question wasn't getting it answered, so I'm reposting it as a much simpler question.  I'm attempting to add to children view and position them at (0, 0) and (100, 100) respectively, but the first view (master) I add ends up filling the whole screen.  My code is very simple, what am I doing wrong that is preventing me from controlling the size and position of the two children views?

**MySplitViewController.m**

```
#import "MySplitViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MYSplitViewController (){}

@property (nonatomic, strong) MasterViewController *masterViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DetailViewController *detailViewController;

@end

@implementation MySplitViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
      self.masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
      self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004);
    [self.view addSubview:self.masterViewController.view];
    [self.masterViewController viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:self.detailViewController.view];
    [self.detailViewController viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

**MasterViewController.m**

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 1004) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    table.dataSource = self;
    table.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:table];
}

@end
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *uiview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 668, 1004)];
    [self.view addSubview:uiview];
}

@end
```

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the frames for `self.masterViewController.view` and `self.detailViewController.view` before adding as subview to `self.view`.

For eg:-

```
self.masterViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
self.detailViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);
```

And you are not supposed to call `viewDidLoad` method directly. It gets called automatically once the view is loaded on the screen.

Comment: Whenever you are adding a view as a subview of another one, you need to set the frame or else it will take the default frame. So in your case it was taking the full screen. From the above code it is clear that you set frame only for 'table' and 'uiview' which are just subviews of 'self.masterViewController.view' and 'self.detailViewController.view' and not same as these two views.

Answer (score 1):

You should create `UIView` derived class for your MySplitViewController view and implement `layoutSubviews` method